# Selecting the 3rd or 4th etc parent element from child element through Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Short cut code for to select the 3rd parent of an child element using Jquery. Could you please help me

Ex:

```
<div>
        <div>
             <div class="child">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
JS
    $('.child').parent().parent()
```

instead of going to this approach, is there any good way to select the parent element in Jquery

Answer (score 1):

Use `.eq()` with `.parents()`

```
$('.child').parents().eq(2);
$('.child').parents().eq(3);
```

`Note:` if you use `.eq(0)`, it will return the first level parent.

Comment: thanks for your ans. eq(4) means?

Comment: eq(4) means 4 th level parent

Comment: suppose by chance if am removing the 2 nd element means it might have point the wrong element right?